# 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server in WAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Just like the title says, I installed wamp, started MySQL and Apache. They are running perfect. When I open this page: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ and I write my id: root and password: root it says this error: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server. Why?

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;



/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

// No warning on  pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not enter any password in phpmyadmin. I remember that there was no default password in WAMP a few versions ago.

Comment: Are you using the default and untouched WAMP configuration?

Comment: I changed mysql password to "root" from mysql console and changed port to be used in 3307. And this : #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080 in httpd.conf

Comment: In your pma configuration file, I don't see the custom port setting. Maybe try to add it.

Comment: If u tell me how I will add it. What to write?